# Error message when rails server is ran

Tags: ruby-on-rails, macos, git

I am trying to run bin/rails server on mac OSX Yosemite with rails version 4.1.6 which gives the error **The git source git://github.com//.git is not yet checked out. Please run `bundle install` before trying to start your application**

As denoted by the error message I ran bundle install

```
Fetching git://github.com//.git fatal: remote error:    Repository not found. Retrying git clone 'git://github.com//.git'
"/Users/veeni/.rbenv/versions/2.1.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/cache/bundler/git/.git-be381fea2c66b8d9e6a5a5f3c7c0cac6c92306af" --bare --no-hardlinks --quiet due to error (2/3): Bundler::Source::Git::GitCommandError Git error: command `git clone 'git://github.com//.git'
"/Users/veeni/.rbenv/versions/2.1.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/cache/bundler/git/.git-be381fea2c66b8d9e6a5a5f3c7c0cac6c92306af" --bare --no-hardlinks --quiet` in directory /Users/veeni/Documents/myprojects/mytest has failed. fatal: remote error:    Repository not found. Retrying git clone 'git://github.com//.git'
"/Users/veeni/.rbenv/versions/2.1.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/cache/bundler/git/.git-be381fea2c66b8d9e6a5a5f3c7c0cac6c92306af" --bare --no-hardlinks --quiet due to error (3/3): Bundler::Source::Git::GitCommandError Git error: command `git clone 'git://github.com//.git'
"/Users/veeni/.rbenv/versions/2.1.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/cache/bundler/git/.git-be381fea2c66b8d9e6a5a5f3c7c0cac6c92306af" --bare --no-hardlinks --quiet` in directory /Users/veeni/Documents/myprojects/mytest has failed. fatal: remote error:    Repository not found. Git error: command `git clone 'git://github.com//.git'
"/Users/veeni/.rbenv/versions/2.1.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/cache/bundler/git/.git-be381fea2c66b8d9e6a5a5f3c7c0cac6c92306af" --bare --no-hardlinks --quiet` in directory /Users/veeni/Documents/myprojects/mytest has failed.
```

The gem file content is

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'


# Bundle edge Rails instead: gem 'rails', github: 'rails/rails' gem 'rails', '4.2.0.rc3'
# Use sqlite3 as the database for Active Record gem 'sqlite3'
# Use SCSS for stylesheets gem 'sass-rails', '~> 5.0'
# Use Uglifier as compressor for JavaScript assets gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.3.0'
# Use CoffeeScript for .coffee assets and views gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 4.1.0'
# See https://github.com/sstephenson/execjs#readme for more supported runtimes
# gem 'therubyracer', platforms: :ruby

# Use jquery as the JavaScript library gem 'jquery-rails'
# Turbolinks makes following links in your web application faster. Read more: https://github.com/rails/turbolinks gem 'turbolinks'
# Build JSON APIs with ease. Read more: https://github.com/rails/jbuilder gem 'jbuilder', '~> 2.0'
# bundle exec rake doc:rails generates the API under doc/api. gem 'sdoc', '~> 0.4.0', group: :doc

# Use ActiveModel has_secure_password
# gem 'bcrypt', '~> 3.1.7'

# Use Unicorn as the app server
# gem 'unicorn'

# Use Capistrano for deployment
# gem 'capistrano-rails', group: :development

group :development, :test do   # Call 'byebug' anywhere in the code to
stop execution and get a debugger console   gem 'byebug'

 # Access an IRB console on exception pages or by using <%= console
%> in views   gem 'web-console', '~> 2.0'

 # Spring speeds up development by keeping your application running
in the background. Read more: https://github.com/rails/spring    

gem'spring'   
gem 'twitter-bootstrap-rails', :git => 'git://github.com/seyhunak/twitter-bootstrap-rails.git' 
gem 'git://github.com/seyhunak/twitter-bootstrap-rails.git' 
gem 'simple_form'    
gem 'momentjs-rails', '>= 2.8.1',  :github => 'derekprior/momentjs-rails' 
gem 'therubyracer'    
gem "less-rails" 
end
```

Anyone knows how to resolve this, please advise, thank you!!

Comment: Could you please provide your `Gemfile` too?

Comment: @maxd thank you for responding!  I just edited the content to include the gem files

Comment: `gem 'git://github.com/seyhunak/twitter-bootstrap-rails.git'` - seems like this string cause your problem.

Comment: [Here](http://bundler.io/v1.8/gemfile.html) is described format of Gemfile. Read it and check your Gemfile.

Comment: @max d yeap thank you so much for your help:) gem 'datetimepicker-rails', :git =>'' is the cause of the error, it should instead be gem 'datetimepicker-rails', github: 'zpaulovics/datetimepicker-rails', branch: 'master', submodules: true

Comment: actually `git:` is a valid option for a gem, you just probably missed something, that's why bundler saw it as an empty repo